# stuck in infinite loop as click on button

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am making an request in react by clicking on a button but I got an error, when i clicked on the button. The infinite request start sending..
And I don't why this happen. I attached my code here, if anyone have any idea about why this bug occur so please tell me.

```
 {loadingDeliver && <Loader />}
                            {userInfo &&
                                userInfo.isAdmin &&
                                order.isPaid &&
                                !order.isDelivered && (
                                    <ListGroup.Item>
                                        <Button
                                            type='button'
                                            className='btn btn-block'
                                            onClick={deliverHandler}
                                        >
                                            Mark As Delivered
                                    </Button>
                                    </ListGroup.Item>
                                )}
```

This is my button when i clicked mark as delivered the infinite request start throwing.
And here is my deliverHandler code:-

```
    const deliverHandler = () => {
        dispatch(deliverOrder(order))
    }
```

Please tell if anyone know why this happen.
If you want to see full code you can go to my github. I have a repo on this.
[1]
This is link to my project. You can go into frontend folder and then in screens folder and then in OrderScreen.js file to see full code.
[1]: https://github.com/piyushmittal20/proShop

Comment: Can you paste your whole code here ? otherwise it will be difficult to debug your code

Comment: I add my github repo link, please you can check there. You find every single file there.

Comment: have you try `onClick={() => deliverHandler()}` ?